# Error en ES6: "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, es6

¿Cómo llamar a un método (desde otro) que se encuentran en la misma clase en NodeJS?

```js
class Usuario{  

    static foo(){  
        let a = this.bar();  
    }    

    bar(){  
        return true;  
    }

}


Usuario.foo();
```

Lo intento de esta forma y retorna:

> TypeError: this.bar is not a function

¿Qué es lo que está mal? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Quizá es por que bar no es `static`, has intentado agregar static a la definicion de la funcion? y llamarlo `Usuario.bar()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás intentando acceder a un método no-estático desde un método estático. Los métodos estáticos son llamados sin instanciar su clase (pertenecen a la clase en sí), mientras que los métodos no estáticos necesitan un objeto (que se haya instanciado la clase).

La solución del problema va a depender del uso que vayas a hacer de `foo()` y `bar()`. Por ejemplo, podrías hacer que `bar` también sea estática:

```js
class Usuario{  

  
    static foo(){  
        let a = this.bar();  
        console.log(a);
    }    

    static bar(){  
        return true;  
    }

}


Usuario.foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación:

Cuerpo de la clase y definición de métodos
Edit

El cuerpo de una clase es la parte que se encuentra entre las llaves {}. Este es el lugar donde se definen los miembros de clase, como los métodos o constructores.
Modo estricto

El cuerpo de las declaraciones de clase y las expresiones de clase son ejecutadas en modo estricto.
Constructor

El método constructor es un método especial para crear e inicializar un objeto creado con una clase. Solo puede haber un método especial con el nombre "constructor" en una clase. Si esta contiene mas de una ocurrencia del método constructor, se arrojará un Error SyntaxError

Un constructor puede usar la palabra reservada super para llamar al constructor de una superclase
Métodos prototipo

[link de la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes)

Ejemplo con tu código:

```
class Usuario{  

get foo(){  
    let a = this.bar();  
}    

bar(){ 
        console.log('si')
    return true;  
}

}

usr = new Usuario
usr.foo;
```

```js
class Usuario{  

    get foo(){  
        let a = this.bar();  
    }    

    bar(){ 
      console.log('Método bar')
        return true;  
    }

}

usr = new Usuario
usr.foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionó arriba un colega, debes agregarle `static` a la función bar, ya que `foo()` está dentro de un contexto estático debe llamar a funciones que así también lo sean.

```js
class Usuario{  

    static foo(){  
        let a = this.bar(); 
        console.log(a);
    }    

    static bar(){  
        return true;  
    }

}

class UsuarioSinStatic {
  foo() {
   let a = this.bar();
        console.log(a);
  }
  
  bar() {
   return true;
  }
}


// Clase estatica
Usuario.foo();

// Clase no estatica
var userSinStatic = new UsuarioSinStatic();
userSinStatic.foo();
```

Para más información sobre los métodos y atributos estáticos te dejo esta [documentación](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com.ar/2013/02/java-static.html) que espero que te sea útil.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No puedes usar `this` en un método estático. Este concepto es aplicado también en lenguajes como Java. Cuando declaras un método estático en una *clase* ES6 que, dicho de paso es una función con prototipo (como siempre), el método **es asociado con el constructor** y no con el prototipo como se espera. Es por eso que **dentro de un método estático no tienes acceso al contexto de la clase**.

Lo correcto es llamar a propiedades y métodos estáticos usando directamente el constructor:

```
Usuario.bar();
```